# Using jQuery to increment an image source and loop through display

Tags: jquery

I have a series photos I want to display. The photos have file names from 1.jpg to 100.jpg, but a few files in the middle are missing. For example, 19.jpg does not exist, but 18.jpg and 20.jpg do. I've written the following code to loop through and display each image, while attempting to skip the ones that don't exist. My problem is the performance is awful. There's a 10-30 second wait before the browser starts to render anything. Is there a different more efficient way I can achieve the same thing without the massive performance hit?

```
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    var src = i + '.jpg';
    if (imageExists(src)) {
        var image = $('<img>').attr('src', src);
        var link = $('<a target="_blank">').attr('href', src);
        var thumbnail = link.append(image);
        thumbnail.appendTo('body');
    }
}   

function imageExists(src){
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', src, false);
    http.send();

    return http.status != 404;
}
```

Comment: in what language is your backend code written to process ajax request?

Comment: You could make an initial call to the server side asking for the list of existing images (e.g.: returning an array of strings with the filenames). Then you can use that to make only the calls for the existing images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd just load them hidden, and give them an `onload` handler that unhides them when they load (or immediately if their `.complete` is set). The ones that don't exist won't get shown.

CSS

```
.img_link.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

JS

```
var htmlArr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  htmlArr.push(`<a target="_blank" class="img_link hidden"><img src="${i}.jpg"></a>`);
}   

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlArr.join(""));

Array.from(document.body.children)
  .filter(el => el.classList.contains("img_link"))
  .map(el => el.firstChild)
  .forEach(img => 
    img.complete ? loader.call(img) : img.addEventListener("load", loader)
  );

function loader() {
  this.parentNode.classList.remove("hidden");
  this.removeEventListener("load", loader);
}
```

***Note:*** the above code uses ES6 syntax. The demo below uses ES5, so use whichever one fits your browser support levels.

---

Click below to see a demo:

```js
var htmlArr = [];
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  var host = i%3==0 ? "example" : "dummyimage";
  htmlArr.push('<a target="_blank" class="img_link hidden"><img src="https://' + host + '.com/120/ff0aff/000000&text=' + i + '"></a>');
}   

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlArr.join(""));

[].slice.call(document.body.children)
  .filter(function(el) { return el.classList.contains("img_link") })
  .map(function(el) { return el.firstChild })
  .forEach(function(img) {
    return img.complete ? loader.call(img) : img.addEventListener("load", loader)
  });

function loader() {
  this.parentNode.classList.remove("hidden");
  this.removeEventListener("load", loader);
}
```

```css
.img_link.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Might want to refactor/transpile your code into ES5, unless OP is familiar with it. Using ES6 might throw people off ;) but otherwise a really pretty answer!

Comment: @Terry: Yeah, good point. I'll give a note and update the live demo so that the have both versions.

Comment: Re your comment on a now-deleted question: Adding a tag name makes the selector slower, not faster, because it adds an extra check. (CSS selectors are mostly processed right-to-left.) It's a common misconception. :-) Though the effect is negligible: https://jsperf.com/tag-name-on-selector/1

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: But that test is flawed, at least potentially. Because you always have the same tag name, then yes, an unqualified selector would be better. But it a more typical, real-world scenario, there would be a diversity of tags. So because of the right-to-left processing that you mentioned, they can start with only the tags of the qualified name, which browsers have likely optimized for anyway due to `getElementsByTagName`. I'd be curious to see the result if only 10% of the tags match the given qualified name.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: You can update the perf to do that, just make sure you're comparing like for like (building a N-element list both ways).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I don't like giving out my github login, but maybe. And you're right, my assertion suggests that the targeted data attribute would be on no other tags, though there could be that tag with no data attribute. Would be tough to find a single representative example. I'll ping you if I decide to try some tests.